# make exist table as inherit

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, inheritance

i try to create parent table for exists table, by next algorithm:

```
-- CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE t1 (id serial PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE foreign_t1 (id serial, t1_id integer REFERENCES t1 (id));
-- insert data
INSERT INTO t1
SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,4);
INSERT INTO foreign_t1
SELECT generate_series, generate_series % 3 + 1
FROM generate_series(1,9);
-- CRETAE PARENT table
CREATE TABLE parent_t1 (LIKE t1 including all);
-- ALTER t1 DO it inherit of the parent
ALTER TABLE t1 INHERIT parent_t1;
-- TRY TO MOVE FK TO the parent
ALTER TABLE foreign_t1 DROP CONSTRAINT foreign_t1_t1_id_fkey;
ALTER TABLE foreign_t1 ADD CONSTRAINT
foreign_t1_t1_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY(t1_id)
REFERENCES parent_t1 (id);
```

But cath the error:

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "foreign_t1" violates foreign key constraint "foreign_t1_t1_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (t1_id)=(2) is not present in table "parent_t1".
```

And when i try to validate the data looks like all exists:

```
dev=# SELECT id FROM parent_t1 WHERE id = 2;
 id 
----
  2
```

i can't understand what i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html):

> A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that....foreign key constraints only apply
>   to single tables, not to their inheritance children.